# cannot find -lmongoclient when trying to compile a program

Tags: c++, mongodb

I try to compile my c++ project, but get this error message: "cannot find -lmongoclient". The way I do it is this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c -fpic -I /usr/include/python2.7 -I /usr/include/mysql -I /usr/include/mysql++ -I mongo-cxx-driver/build/install/include orm.cpp -o corm.o
$ g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,corm.so -o corm.so corm.o -lpython2.7 -lboost_python -lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_regex
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libmongoclient.a when searching for -lmongoclient
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libmongoclient.a when searching for -lmongoclient
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../libmongoclient.a when searching for -lmongoclient
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a when searching for -lmongoclient
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmongoclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'corm.so' failed
make: *** [corm.so] Error 1
```

I'm not sure what else I should specify to make it work. Unfortunately, I have already spent more than two days trying to connect to `mongodb` in `C++`, but to now avail. In `Python` or `PHP` I would make it work literally in seconds, but in `C++` I have to spent eternity just to understand that all I did was totally wrong. Now, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**EDIT**

BTW, the program compiles if I remove `-lmongoclient` and add for example `DSTATIC_LIBMONGOCLIENT` , however, in this case I get another error, when I try to import the module:

```
>>> undefined symbol: blablabla
```

I got a similar problem when I struggled with mysql and this two flags `-lmysqlclient -lmysqlpp` solved the issue. I thought that `-lmongoclient` should do the trick here, but it does not.

Comment: 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system or vice versa?

Comment: I have `linux ubuntu x86_64`. mongodb client was downloaded from here - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#get-the-source-code

Comment: So you compiled the mongoclient library from sources or downloaded a pre-compiled package? In the first escenario make sure you used the same compiler you are using now.

Comment: I compiled the mongoclient library from sources using `scons install`. So, I'm not sure what compiler was used by default.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a prior install (either from a source build or package installation) that has made a /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a? Also, you don't seem to be setting a library search path into the build/install directory of the mongoclient build. Based on the include path that you are setting on the compile line (mongo-cxx-driver/build/install/include), I would expect an analogous -L argument on the link line for your application, something like -L mongo-cxx-driver/build/install/lib. Please also edit your question to include the driver vresion you are building and the SCons invocation.

Comment: @ acm. If I'm not mistaken I installed it like `sudo apt-get install libmongo-client-dev`, but I'm not sure whether `/usr/lib/libmongoclient.a` is a result of this command or not. As for driver versions and Scons I will report about it in a minute.

Comment: `-L mongo-cxx-driver/build/install/lib` solved the problem. Thank you so much! I think future programmers from Python or other world coming to C++ will face the same problems as I did. And a tiny typical example with appropriate compilation and linkage stage (with `-I .../include` and `-L .../lib` flags included) specification will save them dozens of hours.

Comment: @Jacobian You should write that up as an answer to this question! (You're allowed to answer your own questions.)

Comment: @melpomene Actually, acm has answered to the question. +100500 of reputation to him :)

Comment: @Jacobian But that's just a comment, so stackoverflow still lists this as an "unanswered" question.

Comment: It will be fair, if we wait a little bit, until acm decides or not to answer himself.

Comment: Nah, I don't do the driver ones for karma.